# Common Code for Activity and PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, class

I'm using common code in my Activity like this:

```
abstract class CommonCode extends Activity {
    //Common Code here...
}
```

then in my "Activity" I extend CommonCode instead of Activity and it all works fine.

My problem arise when I try to use commoncode in a PreferenceActivity, I tried:

```
abstract class CommonCode extends Activity {

    class CommonCodePreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    }
    //Common Code here...
}
```

but it isn't right.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually have one each since you can't mess with the existing hierarchy of the base classes.

For example, I have an ActivityBase, ServiceBase, ListActivityBase, etc.  If you want to have common code that they all use, I would suggest using composition - each of your base classes has a single instance of your CommonCode class or something to that effect.  Another possibility is to use static methods and/or use a custom Application class (requires declaring the custom Application class in the manifest in the name attribute of the application element)

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest that you prefer composition over inheritance and do something like this:

```
abstract class CommonCode {

  Activity parent;

  public CommonCode(Activity activity) {
    parent = activity;
  }

}

class MyActivity extends Activity {

   CommonCode commonCode;

   public MyActivity() {
      commonCode = new CommonCode(this);
   }

}
```

This is a little more code to write in each activity, but it has a lot of advantages:

- It can also easily handle PreferenceActivity and other classes
- It is easier to test and mock